# I have been asked to download Trust wallet, and was sent funds from watch only address. Sender is asking me to deposit $200 from cash app to get 5k

Tags: fraud, watch-only, cash-app

Someone asked me to open a watchwallet. Sent me over 2k “on watch” asking me to send them $200 to their cash app in order to get my $200 back, keep all the money in my watch wallet, and another 5k.  This has to be a scam yes?

Comment: See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=Watch+only+scam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely a scam.

A 'watch only' address is one that you don't have the means of spending. The blockchain record is all public record, so you can just literally watch any address you want to see if any coins are held in it. Anyone can do this.

The person who is trying to scam you might not even have access to those funds. They may have just chosen a random address for you to watch.

Watch-only addresses are not 'unlocked' by sending money to anyone. The person you send the money to will likely just disappear, along with your money. Why would they send you anything back?