# I was asked to download trust wallet and was than sent around $5000 in watch only. Than was told to ask to access Bitcoin on my cash app. Is it real?

Tags: fraud, watch-only, cash-app

I was asked to download trust wallet and was than sent around $5000 in watch only. I than was told to ask to access Bitcoin on my cash app. They said to access Bitcoin and than send a screenshot after it’s done. Is it real or a scam? Do they have a way to get me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Someone else created a wallet for me to use. Is this a scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/88910/someone-else-created-a-wallet-for-me-to-use-is-this-a-scam)

Comment: Also see: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/115039

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a scam to me.
A watch only wallet does not allow you to spend the bitcoin within it as it only consists of public keys.
In order to send funds to CashApp, you would have to have the private key, which you clearly don't have.